# Are user code in the end executed in kernel mode?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, kernel

For what i learned from Operating System Concepts and online searching:

1. all user threads are finally mapped to kernel threads for being scheduled to physical CPUs
2. kernel threads can only be executed in kernel mode

above two arguments leads to the conclusion:

1. user code are all executed in kernel mode

is this right?

i have read the whole book and searched for many articles, the question still holds.

at Wikipedia, it says about LWP:

> Kernel threads
> Kernel threads are handled entirely by the kernel. They need not be associated with a process; a kernel can create them whenever it needs to perform a particular task. Kernel threads cannot execute in user mode. LWPs (in systems where they are a separate layer) bind to kernel threads and provide a user-level context. This includes a link to the shared resources of the process to which the LWP belongs. When a LWP is suspended, it needs to store its user-level registers until it resumes, and the underlying kernel thread must also store its own kernel-level registers.

also what does it means when saying about user-level registers and kernel level registers?

---

after digging and digging, i have following temp conclusion, but i am not sure. Hope the question further be answered and clearifed:

`kernel thread`, depending on discussion context, has two meanings:

1. when talking about user/kernel threading, kernel thread means a kernel task that totally execute in kernel mode and only execute kernel codes, like `ksoftirqd` for handling bottom half of interrupts
2. when taking about threading model, namely how user code is mapped into schedulable entities in kernel, kernel thread means a task that is schedulable by kernel

further about threading model and light weight processes in Linux:

1. in old times the operating system does not know thread, it only know processes(tasks) and threads are implmented by thread libraries totally in user side. There is a inherent problem for this that is if one user thread is blocked, such as I/O, all the user threads are blocked, because there is only one schedulable tasks in the kernel for this process. From the perspective of the kernel, the whole process is blocked. To solve this problem, light weight process(LWP), also called virtual processor(VP) is invented.
2. LWP is a intermedia data structure between user thread and a kernel thread(the second meaning above). LWP binds a user thread with a kernel thread(task), which in before is bounded with a user process. Simply put: in before a user process occupies a kernel thread(task), now with LWP a user thread can occupy a individual kernel thread(task), without sharing it with other user threads. (I think) This is why it is called *light weight process*. The advantage of this model is obvious, if one of the user thread is blocked, other user threads has ways to continue being executed by other kernel threads(tasks).
3. A kernel thread(task) acutually knows nothing about user process. It is just a task, a schedulable entity created, managed, destroyed totally by kernel itself. But a LWP belongs to a specific process and knows other LWPs that also belongs to the same one.  LWP is like a bridge between user process and kernel thread(task).
4. When a kernel thread(task) that is bound to a LWP is scheduled by the kernel, the user level registers(pointed by LWP) is loaded into CPU, also the kernel thread(task) has registers and they are also loaded into CPU. From the standing point of CPU, a LWP *is* a kernel thread(task). It does not care it executes kernel code or user code.
5. user/kernel mode, user/kernel thread: they are independent. In Linux, a user thread created by `pthread` essentially *is* a kernel thread and this thread can execute in both user mode or kernel mode, depending on whether the thread is executing user code or kernel code.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different meanings of kernel threads. When threading people talk about "kernel threads" they mean "threads the kernel knows about" i.e. "threads that are controlled by the kernel". When kernel people talk about "kernel threads" they mean "threads that run in kernel mode".

"Threads the kernel knows about" are contrasted to "user threads" which are hidden from the kernel and controlled by the program itself.

No, not all threads controlled by the kernel run in kernel mode. The kernel controls the scheduling of threads that run in kernel mode, and also threads that run in user mode.

---

The quote about LWPs is talking about systems where the scheduler thinks that *all* threads are kernel-mode threads. To run a user-mode thread (which they call an LWP because it's not really a thread because all threads are kernel-mode threads) the thread has to call a function like `RunLWP(pointer_to_lwp);`.

I don't know which system is like this. Linux is not like this; Windows is not like this. This is a weird, overly complicated design which is why it's not normally used.

The "registers" are where the CPU remembers what it is currently doing. The most important one is the "instruction pointer" register (some CPUs call it something different) which remembers which instruction is next. If you remember all of the register values, and then come back later and set them to the same values, the CPU will carry on like nothing happened. That's why threading works - the thread can't tell that it's been interrupted, because all of the registers have the same values as if it wasn't interrupted. [Here's a list of registers on x86-class CPUs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture). You don't need to know them for this question - it just might be interesting.

When an interrupt happens, depending on the CPU type, the CPU will save the instruction pointer and maybe one or two other registers. The interrupt handler has to save the rest (or be careful not to change them). [Here about halfway down](https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/os-interrupts/) you can see how an x86-class CPU switches from user-space to an interrupt handler when an interrupt occurs.

So this `RunLWP` function would save the current registers (from the kernel) and set them according to the last time the LWP stopped running. Then the LWP runs. Then when some interrupt happens, the interrupt handler would save the current registers (from user-space) and set them according to the saved kernel handlers, so the kernel code after `RunLWP` runs. Probably. Again, I don't know any actual system like this, but it seems like the logical way to do things. The reason it should return back to the kernel code instead of the user code is so that the kernel code can decide whether it wants to keep running the LWP or not.

I don't know why they would say the interrupt handler would save both the kernel-space and user-space registers. Current CPUs generally only have one set of registers which software has to swap out when it wants to make the CPU change what it is doing. `RunLWP` would have to save the kernel registers and load the user ones, then the interrupt handler would have to save the user registers and load the interrupt handler ones. It could be that the CPUs which these systems were designed for *did* have two sets of registers.

Comment: if a user thread is mapped to a kernel thread, does it occupies a kernel thread id? i update the Wikipedia quote, what is the meaning of user-level registers and kernel level registers?

Comment: @shan It depends on the specific operating system. I don't think Linux has this LWP/kernel thread thing. On Linux a thread is running in user mode or kernel mode, not both at the same time. Same for Windows. But I can see what it means so maybe I will explain it - even though I don't know what OS it is talking about

Comment: @shan I started explaining the LWP thing but then I went home for the weekend and forgot to post it, so I'll post it on Monday, probably. Note that there's no law of physics that says every operating system has to be the same. This LWP and mapping thing only applies to a few operating systems, and it's not widely used, because it is too complicated.

Comment: since I mostly work on Linux, sorry that i didn't specifiy the os at the beginning.  However it's even better if you can bring implementation detailed from other os, such as Windows, into the disscussion. I would like to get the whole picture. @user253751

Comment: @shan I posted the edit

Comment: "did have two sets of registers", that's what i currently believe now, maybe i need to go deeper in CPU registers to understand this. However, Linux does have LWP concept, it's a one to one mapping from user-thread to kernel thread, using LWP. You can check with `ps -fL` command. The pthread POSIX API does so good  a job that most of the time we do not care what happens when we create a user thread, only knowing that we create a kernel thread that can take advantage of multi core resources. @user253751

Comment: This article demonstrate  [Create LWP in Linux](https://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/08/light-weight-processes-dissecting-linux-threads/)

Comment: @shan I don't think it's the same thing being talked about with your definition of LWP. Even if you call them the same name, they do not work like your definition.

Answer (score 3):

> All user threads are finally mapped to kernel threads.

That is not a useful way to think about threads. In most operating systems, a program can ask the OS to create a new thread and the program can provide a pointer to a function for the new thread to call. There's no "mapping" that happens there.* The new thread runs in exactly the same way as the program's original (a.k.a., "main") thread. It runs application code in user mode except, occasionally, when it makes a system call, and then for the duration of the system call it runs kernel code in kernel mode.

Many programming languages come with an OS-independent library that provides some kind of a `Thread` *object.* The thread object is *not* the same thing as the actual thread. It's more of a handle that the application uses to control the OS thread. If you like, you can say that those thread *objects* are "mapped" to OS threads, but that's still somewhat abusing the notion of what a "mapping" is.

> kernel threads can only be executed in kernel mode

If you aren't writing OS code, it's best to avoid saying "kernel thread" altogether. In the Linux OS in particular, "kernel thread" means something, and it has nothing whatever to do with application code. Linux kernel threads are threads that are created *by* the OS *for* the OS, and they never run "user" (i.e., application) code.

It's possible for an application program to create and schedule its own threads, completely unknown to the OS. Some people call those "user threads." Some used to call them "green threads." Back in the old days, before any OS had thread support, we just called them "threads." Doing threads that way is a lot of work, for little reward. (Can't schedule them preemptively.) Outside of the realm of tiny, embedded, real-time systems, almost nobody bothers to do it anymore.

---

* But wait! Things will get more complicated in the near future when Java's [Project Loom](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/java-project-loom) hits the main stream. Threads traditionally are *expensive.* In particular, each thread must have its own contiguous call stack—usually a chunk of at least a few megabytes—allocated to it. The goal of project loom is to make threads as cheap as any other object.

They way they intend to make threads "cheap" is to "virtualize" them, and to break up their call stacks into linked lists of reclaimable heap objects. Under project loom, a limited number of real OS threads that are scheduled by the OS scheduler will, in turn, schedule and execute the code of a multitude of "virtual" application threads, and so there really will be something going on that feels a bit like "mapping."

I won't be at all surprised if the same idea spreads to other languages.